# Viduy on motzaeh shabbat?

Tags: shema, motzei-shabbos, viduy-confession

If one has the custom to say viduy during kriat shema al hamitah, can he say this viduy following shabbat since motzeh shabbat is sort of a half holiday?

Comment: How do you know that *motza'ei shabbat* is considered a "half holiday"?

Answer (score 3):

*Sha'arei Teshuvah* ([300:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1508)) writes in the name of the Arizal that it is forbidden to say *viduy* on *motzaei shabbos* until after *chatzos*.

*Chesed La'alafim* ([131:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7849&st=&pgnum=242)) writes the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, *Motzei Shabbat* is still considered festive, so one shouldn't say *viduy* (if you go to sleep before midnight, by "שעות זמניות").

Sources:

- http://din.org.il/2015/12/06/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA/
- http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/96073-%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA
- http://www.hidabroot.org/he/question/33988

Comment: MIGDOL in BhMz.

Comment: While all these sites claim such, they don't bring any sources to support their claims.